# Can I setup a SKPhysicsJoint in separate .m file (character)

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint, skphysicsworld

I'm quite new to SpriteKit and coding in general. I am trying to setup a SKPhysicsJoint in my characters .m file. However, I can't use the physicsWorld syntax as it is not a scene.

How would i get round this?

I have a parent node with two children inside, one small circle sprite with a physicsBody of the same size. I want to add a second circle physicsBody twice the radius with the same centre point. This is so I can handle collisions at different distances.

I've tried defining the SKPhysicsJoint in my characters .h file and using physicsWorld in the scene file but this didn't work.

I'm I going about this the right way or is a much simpler solution that I have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

### Here:

If the nodes in your character class are added to your SKScene then you
can retrieve the SKPhysicsWorld this way: node.scene.physicsWorld